# WPF: Microsoft_Windows_Themes not found

Tags: wpf, themes

I am getting this error in my WPF app:

The type 'Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Any idea?

Answer (score 41):

Make sure you add this reference in the top most tag of your control/page/resource dictionary/whatever:

...

```
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
```

And add a reference to `PresentationFramework.Aero` in your project.