# WPF Button icon gets mirrored, why?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, icons

This Button looks fine (see screenshot) when defining the image as done below. Note that the shield shaped icon with the letter 'T' is visualized correctly.

```
<Button Command="w:MainWindow.BrowseTorrentSite">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="../icons/kickasstorrent.png" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

[image]

When I want to rely on the buttons enabled state, the icon gets mirrored.

```
<StackPanel 
      Orientation="Horizontal" 
      FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
        <Button 
            x:Name="KatButton" 
            Command="w:MainWindow.BrowseTorrentSite">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image>
                    <Image.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Image">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" 
                                    Value="True">

                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="../icons/kickasstorrent.png" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger 
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" 
                                    Value="False">

                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="../icons/kickasstorrent_disabled.png" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Image.Style>
                </Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

**Note the shield shaped icon with the letter 'T' is now mirrored.**

What is responsible for mirroring the icon?

If somebody has tips to debug this in whatever way possible, feel free to point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is in the parent StackPanel. If the `StackPanel` is defining the `FlowDirection` from right to left, the `Image` definition inherits this property which results in the flipped icon.

To solve this problem redefine left to right on the image itself.

```
    <StackPanel 
        Orientation="Horizontal" 
        FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
        <Button>
            <Image FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                <Image.Style>
                    <!-- etc etc -->
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
       </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```