# CheckBox tick mirrored when changing FlowDirection

Tags: wpf

O.S. : Microsoft Windows 8.1
Developing Application: Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 (WPF App development)

I have moved from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 and now my old apps which i had developed in VS2012 have a weird manner. because my language is right-to-left, i use `RightToLeft` for `FlowDirection`. it was working fine as all text was showing on the left side of `CheckBox` but now the tick sign of `CheckBox` is mirrored like this:

[image]

the tick sign is not correct even in a right-to-left language. is this because O.S. or the VS2013 and how can i fix it? do i need to create a template? thanks.

Comment: normally it is not the case, tick remains normal. are you using any third party controls? could you post the template used or the control (if any)? also post how you are using the check box in your xaml.

Comment: i don't use any third-party controls. just simple checkbox and again: it is working good on windows 7 or maybe in vs2012 because after changing to windows 8.1 and vs2013 it does so

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem, and this is the best solution i found. The path is what draws the tick, so just changing its flow direction back to LeftToRight makes it draw as you would expect.

```
<CheckBox Content="My Checkbox" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <CheckBox.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
               <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
         </Style>
    </CheckBox.Resources>
</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ArabicStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                    <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <CheckBox Content="My Checkbox:" Style="{StaticResource ArabicStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Nice, even better than the accepted answer since I don't have to put it on every checkbox. I'd never thought of putting resources in a style for some reason. This is a nice new tool for me to use.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use standard Checkbox Control, set FlowDirection of path to LeftToRight  will work but if you create a custom template it doesn't work so  Make a custom Style template for CheckBox like this and set      FlowDirection of main Grid to LeftToRight" :

```
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource MyFocusVisualStyte}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <BulletDecorator>
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <!-- ****************** here set FlowDirection to LeftToRight *********************************** -->
                            <Grid      FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Height, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          MinHeight="30" MinWidth="30" ShowGridLines="False">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Border Name="MainBorder"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="9" Grid.RowSpan="9"
                                CornerRadius="4"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                Background="Transparent" />

                                <Border Name="InnerBorder"
                                Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                                Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                BorderBrush="#808080" />

                                <Path Name="InnerPath"

                              Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                              Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                              Data="M31,5 L19.5,5 19.5,19.5 34.5,19.5 34.5,11.75"
                              Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Red"/>

                                <Path Name="CheckMark"
                              Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                              Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                              Opacity="0"
                              Data="M9.07743946676476E-09,4.31805768640244L4.68740335877841,8.86361158398516C4.68740335877841,8.86361158398516,16.3281249985376,-2.42451336648723,16.3281249985376,-2.42451336648723L14.0622100581796,-4.77304938341948 4.68740335877846,4.31805791992662 2.22656251699567,1.93164208562579z"
                              Fill="#3babe3"
                              Stretch="Fill"
                              Stroke="#3babe3" />

                                <Path Name="InderminateMark"
                              Grid.Column="3"
                              Grid.Row="4"
                              Data="M0,4 L1,5 5,1 4,0"
                              Opacity="0"
                              Stretch="Fill"
                              StrokeThickness="0"
                              Fill="#808080" />
                            </Grid>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Duration="0:0:0.2" To="1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" >
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="InderminateMark" Duration="0:0:0.2" To="1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,4,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    </BulletDecorator>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="MainBorder" Property="Background" Value="#81d2eb" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Fill" Value="#cccccc" />
                            <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Stroke" Value="#cccccc" />
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerPath" Property="Stroke" Value="#cccccc" />
                            <Setter TargetName="InderminateMark" Property="Fill" Value="#cccccc" />
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#cccccc" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MyFocusVisualStyte" >
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusStyle" StrokeDashArray="4 4" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Fill="Transparent"
                       Stroke="#81d2eb" StrokeThickness="1" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically all you need to do is change CheckBox.FlowDirection="RightToLeft". However, this causes the check mark to be mirrored (a bug in my opinion). Therefore, you need to recreate the control. Begin by creating a UserControl and replace it with this;

```
<CheckBox ... >
   <CheckBox.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
         <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight" />
      </Style>
   </CheckBox.Resources>
</CheckBox>
```

Literally change the UserControl tag to CheckBox instead. Furthermore, change the inheritance in the code behind from UserControl to CheckBox. This may look strange but, trust me, it works. The new control behaves exactly the same as the CheckBox, except that implements the check mark bug fix. That is, the FlowDirection property will now work as expected.

Cheers