# Checkbox tick direction

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox

I have a checkbox as per the photo below. I'm curious why my 'checked' symbol look so weird and laterally inverted. I intentionally to use FlowDirection ="RightToLeft" is to ensure my text is at left side of the checkbox.

[image]

Below are my XMAL:

```xml
<CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" Content="Stop Immediately"
          IsChecked="{Binding StopImmediately}" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
          Margin="-30,15,5,0" />
```

Comment: You set `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"`, which affects the rendering of the checkbox (note the text is on the left side of the checkbox too). Why did you choose `RightToLeft` if you don't want right-to-left layout?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CheckBox tick mirrored when changing FlowDirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217199/checkbox-tick-mirrored-when-changing-flowdirection)

Answer (score 0):

Liew,

I can see that you want the Text to be on the left side of the checkbox, but you want the tick direction to function normally. Here is a solution to your problem:

```
  <CheckBox FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Grid.Row="9"
            IsChecked="{Binding StopImmediately}" 
            Margin="-30,15,5,0">
            <TextBlock FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Text="Stop Immediately" />
        </CheckBox>
```

Does this solve your problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for the reply! I had changed to the xaml as per your instructed, but the check mark still laterally inverted :(