# Fix checkbox + textblock WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How I can fix it?

[[image]

```
<CheckBox
    x:Name="///"
    Grid.Row="3"
    Grid.Column="0"
    IsChecked="{Binding ///, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Style="{DynamicResource ///}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <CheckBox.Content>
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Style="{DynamicResource ///}" />
    </CheckBox.Content>
</CheckBox>
```

I need to align this square to the left and the text to the right
but for some reason the square is constantly centered

Comment: You might want to add some info on what your problem is and what you are trying to achieve. [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I need to align this square to the left and the text to the right
but for some reason the square is constantly centered

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue. Can you try removing your styles and see if the problem persists. Or post your styles here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to set the content. You can define a TextBlock inside the Checkbox

```
<CheckBox>
    <TextBlock Text="MyCaption" />
</CheckBox>
```

Square to the left and label to the right is the normal behavior. Doing it the other way around is [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465867/text-on-the-left-side-of-checkbox-in-wpf).